# Problems with git clone

Tags: ssh, git, https, github

I have a problem cloning a repo when I use http:

```
git clone https://github.com/burbanox/responsive-design.git
```

throw me an error :

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/burbanox/responsive-design.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
```

so when I use ssh:

```
git clone git@github.com:burbanox/responsive-design.git
```

stays loading forever :

```
Cloning into 'responsive-design'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 115, done.
remote: Counting objects:   6% (7/115)
```

I use ubuntu 20.04 LTS
I change to Openssl but not works

Comment: you using WSL2?

Answer (score 2):

1. Install missing packages with the following command.

   ```
   sudo apt install build-essential nghttp2 libnghttp2-dev libssl-dev
   ```
2. If that doesn't work check if Ubuntu is behind a proxy, and if so modify `~/.gitconfig` adding the proxy configuration:

   ```
   touch ~/.gitconfig
   [http]
       proxy = http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:pppp
   ```
3. If that doesn't work and if you are using a VPN, drop your VPN connection and reconnect to the VPN.

Comment: I have a feeling it is number 2, and the proxy is a Windows OS. XD

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in WSL2 installations of git.

See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5346)

I'm guessing you are using Git inside of WSL. If so, be sure to add your issue to the feed in the link.

Even if it has already been said many times in the same feed, they judge priority based at least partly on community feedback. Your voice is important here.